# BotClean challenge

Tags: ruby, programming-challenge, ai

I'm going through the artificial intelligence domain at HackerRank. I'm very new to this domain and I really need a guide on how should I minimize the number of `if`/`else` statements in my code.

#### Problem Statement

> The goal of Artificial Intelligence is to create a rational agent
>   (Artificial Intelligence 1.1.4). An agent gets input from the
>   environment through sensors and acts on the environment with
>   actuators. In this challenge, you will program a simple bot to perform
>   the correct actions based on environmental input.
>
> Meet the bot MarkZoid. It's a cleaning bot whose sensor is a head
>   mounted camera and whose actuators are the wheels beneath it. It's
>   used to clean the floor.
>
> The bot here is positioned at the top left corner of a 5*5 grid. Your
>   task is to move the bot to clean all the dirty cells.

### Input Format

> The first line contains two space separated integers which indicate
>   the current position of the bot. The board is indexed using Matrix
>   Convention 5 lines follow representing the grid. Each cell in the grid
>   is represented by any of the following 3 characters: 'b' (ascii value
>   98) indicates the bot's current position, 'd' (ascii value 100)
>   indicates a dirty cell and '-' (ascii value 45) indicates a clean cell
>   in the grid.
>
> Note If the bot is on a dirty cell, the cell will still have 'd' on
>   it.

### Output Format

> The output is the action that is taken by the bot in the current step,
>   and it can be either one of the movements in 4 directions or cleaning
>   up the cell in which it is currently located. The valid output strings
>   are LEFT, RIGHT, UP and DOWN or CLEAN. If the bot ever reaches a dirty
>   cell, output CLEAN to clean the dirty cell. Repeat this process until
>   all the cells on the grid are cleaned.

### Sample Input #00

```
0 0
b---d
-d--d
--dd-
--d--
----d
```

### Sample Output #00

```
RIGHT
```

### Resultant state

```
-b--d
-d--d
--dd-
--d--
----d
```

### Sample Input #01

```
0 1
-b--d
-d--d
--dd-
--d--
----d
```

### Sample Output #01

```
DOWN
```

### Resultant state

```
----d
-d--d
--dd-
--d--
----d
```

### Code

The algorithm I'm using is simple: I will first search for wether the bot is in the same row as the cell if it is not it will go up/down as required. Then, I will do the same for column.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
def next_move posr, posc, board
    if board[posr][posc] == 'd'
        puts 'CLEAN'
    elsif board[posr].include? 'd'
        val = posc - board[posr].index('d')
        if val < 0
            puts 'RIGHT'
        else
            puts 'LEFT'
        end
    else
        if posr == 0
            puts 'DOWN'
        else 
            board.each_with_index do |value, index|
                if value.include? 'd'
                    i = index - posr
                    if i < 0
                        puts 'UP'
                    else
                        puts 'DOWN'
                    end
                    break
                end
            end
        end
    end     
end
pos = gets.split.map {|i| i.to_i}
board = Array.new(5)

(0...5).each do |i|
    board[i] = gets.strip
end

puts next_move pos[0], pos[1], board
```

Comment: Could you add a quick description of what formula your bot uses to determine where it should go? It'll make it easier to review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### General tips

- Good, clear variable names are important. While `posr` and `posc` might be perfectly clear to you, the more conventional (and therefore more understandable) way to name variables used that way is with `row` and `col`/`column`.
- In function declarations, you should *always* have parentheses around the arguments, if for no other reason than to make it easier to read.
- Indents in Ruby are typically two spaces. Functionally, it's the same as four, but that's the convention I've seen.
- You should always have a space before and after `do` and `end` (or `{` and `}` when they're used in that context), so (for example) this:

  ```
  pos = gets.split.map {|i| i.to_i}
  ```

  becomes this:

  ```
  pos = gets.split.map { |i| i.to_i }
  ```

---

#### Specific stuff

- Your `board` building bit is a bit confusing -- maybe I just need coffee, but it took me two reads to get how it worked. I'd suggest something like this (using the optional block in [`Array#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new)):

  ```
  board = Array.new(5) { gets.chomp }
  ```

  It initializes an array of five elements, and each element is set to the return result of `gets` (`.chomp` strips the EOL). Much cleaner, IMO.
- For some reason, you `puts` the result of `next_move`, but... `next_move` doesn't return anything. You're already `put`ting everything in the method. Change all of your `puts` calls, except the one at the very end, to `return`, or remove the `puts` at the very end. Personally, I'd do the former, though I can't articulate why.
- Rather than using `i.to_i`, I'd suggest using `Integer(i)`. That means it'll fail with an error if you, for example, try to provide `;` as one of the coordinates. `to_i` just fails silently (and returns 0). See the docs for [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-to_i) and [`Integer()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) for more information.
- As for the meat of your code, though... The algorithm looks good to me. It took me a little while to get it (I *really* need coffee) but once I did, it was pretty simple.
- You asked about getting rid of your `if`s, but I don't really think you need to. Sometimes code just needs a lot of nested conditionals; they're not an anti-pattern, just uncommon. If you *really* want to, you could use the techniques suggested in the other answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/92856/62850):

  - Replace things like

    ```
    if board[posr][posc] == 'd'
        return 'CLEAN'
    elsif #...
    ```

    with

    ```
    return 'CLEAN' if board[posr][posc] == 'd'
    if #...
    ```

    (Note that I'm assuming you followed my advice to use `return` instead of `puts`; it makes things a lot easier.)
  - Replace everything you can with ternaries, and simplify more! For example, this:

    ```
    return 'UP' if index - row < 0
    'DOWN'
    ```

    becomes this:

    ```
    index - row < 0 ? 'UP' : 'DOWN'
    ```

    Then we can apply the previous tip to the result after this substitution. See the final code for the result.

With all of these suggestions (including the last, since you want it), here's what your code becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
def next_move(row, col, board)
  return 'CLEAN' if board[row][col] == 'd'
  return (col - board[row].index('d') < 0) ? 'RIGHT' : 'LEFT' if board[row].include? 'd'
  return 'DOWN' if row == 0
  board.each_with_index do |value, index|
    return index - row < 0 ? 'UP' : 'DOWN' if value.include? 'd'
  end
end

pos = gets.split.map { |i| Integer(i) }
board = Array.new(5) { gets.chomp }

puts next_move pos[0], pos[1], board
```

(Note: I decided not to use the implicit return anywhere because it's just simpler to understand that way, with how many places this method returns)

Answer (score 1):

### Guard clauses

One way to get away with less `if` expressions is to use guard clauses: https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses

For example, you can get rid of your first `if` by converting it to a guard clause:

```
if board[posr][posc] == 'd'
  puts 'CLEAN'
```

Becomes:

```
puts 'CLEAN' if board[posr][posc] == 'd'
```

And then your `elsif` will just be an `if`. Another thing you can do is to use ternary conditions.

---

### Ternary conditions

Ternary conditions have the following form:

```
condition ? true : false
```

So you could convert this:

```
if val < 0
  puts 'RIGHT'
else
  puts 'LEFT'
end
```

Into this:

```
puts val < 0 ? 'RIGHT' : 'LEFT'
```

This gives you a more compact `if / else` expression.

---

Here is an example:

```
def next_move(row, col, board)
  return 'CLEAN' if board[row][col] == 'd'

  if board[row].include? 'd'
    (col - board[row].index('d') < 0) ? 'RIGHT' : 'LEFT'
  else    
    row >= board.size ? 'UP' : 'DOWN'
  end
end
```

Comment: If you propose guard clauses, why don't you actually use them in your solution? It would make it look less like a code dump

Comment: Because I already had this solution from when I solved this one year ago, but I thought it would be a good idea to mention guard clauses since he specifically asked about 'how to minimize the number of if/else statements'.

Comment: He asked that, but looking at his code, it's not clear how your suggestion about guard clauses can be applied to his code. You might want to clarify that.